# Aws iot core does not store data in dynamodb

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-iot-core

Just started with AWS IoT Core. My data is collected through MQTT and i receive the message in my IoT core. The next step is to store the data into an AWS Dynamodb table, after following this tutorial : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/iot/latest/developerguide/iot-ddb-rule.html
I'm not able to store or write any data into the tables.

My incomming messages looks like this: (all under topic_1 for testing)

```
> {   "GEG_BIO1_PHT_01": "7.631945",   "GEG_BIO1_PT01_LEIDING":
> "298.0324",   "GEG_BIO1_PT01_MATTEN": "68.03241",  
> "GEG_BIO1_PT01_OPSTART": "43.2",   "GEG_BIO1_S_01": "30",  
> "GEG_BIO1_TT_01": "14.40972",   "GEG_BIO2_O2T_01": "8.645833",  
> "GEG_BIO_CYCLI": "6787",   "GEG_BIO_EFFL": "6793",   "GEG_BIO_NIVEAU":
> "230",   "GEG_BUF1_LT01_M3": "1049.768",   "GEG_BUF1_LT_01":
> "9.447917",   "GEG_BUF2_LT01_M3": "1001.157",   "GEG_BUF2_LT_01":
> "9.010417",   "GEG_INFL_BUFFER1_2": "0",   "GEG_REST_STAP_BIO": "36", 
> "GEG_STAP_BIO": "3",   "M_alarm": "0",   "M_nieuw_alarm": "1",  
> "STAP6": "30",   "STATUS_BIO1_S_01": "1",   "STATUS_BIO2_P_01": "0",  
> "STATUS_BIO2_P_02": "1",   "time": "2022-10-01 05:09:46.000z" }
```

I've configured the table with a primary_key : time. and sort_key empty.
I created a aws rule:

```
SELECT * FROM 'topic_1'
```

and the name of my table is vopak_data.
Also selected the dynamodbv2 to split my messages into multiple columns.

this is my rule configuration at the moment:
[image: ![Rule config]

Can someone help me out ?
Thanks!

Comment: Create also an error action and republish to a topic to see what is wrong. Also, remember to update the role used by iot rule to push data into DDB and publish to iot for the error action.

Comment: Publish seem to work. checked everything again, updated the rule. But not able to find any published data? Also created an error role but it's not throwing any error.

Comment: I tested and it works for me. Make sure the role used by iot rule is able to put item in DDB. Is DynamoDB in the same account/region?

Comment: Yep both in region paris, i've added the config. it the same as the tutorial can't see whats wrong

Comment: This is not DDBv2 config but normal DDB. Please use DDBv2

Comment: I know but both doesn't seem to work

Comment: please share the wx_ddb_role. I used DDv2 action with your payload and it works.

Comment: Ok, It seems to work now. if created a new role. I think the old one had some test configurations left

Answer (score 1):

From my perspective it looks to be caused by your data type for your Sort Key. You cast something to a Decimal but you have declared the Sort Key to be a String, which would cause a mismatch. Change the Sort key to Number type and give it a try.

For some reason you also state that you have left Sort key empty but you have not?

Comment: changed to numbers still nothing showing up.

Comment: I'm not an IOT specialist, but are the keys you are selecting valid values? I suggest removing the sort key completely and trying. As I see `time` exists in your payload.

Comment: Broke it down to a simple as i could but none of these seem to work either, im assuming something is wrong within the query

Comment: So you created a table with a pk of time and no SK? Can you share the describe-table command output?